# Convert multiple array into one single array list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have multiple 1-element lists that I wish to convert into 1 single list:

Current lists:

```
['orange']
['apple']
['grape']
['banana']
['mango']
```

Wish to have an output like this:

```
['orannge', 'apple', 'grape', 'banana', 'mango']
```

My purpose is to write those array with 1x3 into a csv file

Here is Code:

```
import csv
#import numpy as np

f1 = open('out.csv')
data = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=':')
print (data)
for row in data:
    #print(row)
    modules = print(row[2:])
    #for row in module:

    result = [[0,0]]

# iterate through rows
for i in modules:
    # iterate through columns
    for j in modules[0]:
        result[j][i] = X[i][j]

for r in result:
    print(r)  

#Try with zip/map
#print(map(data,zip(*module))
#with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    #writer = csv.writer(f)
    #for row in module:
    #writer.writerow(module)
f1.close()
```

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about what you already tried?

Comment: I tried with transpose matrix(error), numpy (i am using python 3 fail to install numpy), map/zip etc

Comment: From the context of your question, it's not clear why you would use matrix or numpy to achieve this task; you might want to elaborate your question and maybe provide some codes you've written

Comment: How do you keep those arrays currently? Are they in a list of lists like [["..."],["...],] or are they named entities like a = ["orange"] ? How many lists are we talking about aprox. ?

Comment: I am keeping them in [["..."],["...],] approximately got 1k data. I would like to write those 1x10000 array form data in csv file

Comment: Your code seems to be doing something not related to your description. I think you can get rid of it.

Comment: Do you have any idea how too do this? I read a csv file with 1000X1 then i wish to convert it into 1x1000 then write into csv file again

Answer (score 0):

Since you are keeping a list of lists just flatten the list like so:

```
inputlist = [['orange'],['apple'],['grape'],['banana'],['mango']]
outputlist = []
for i in inputlist:
  outputlist.append(i[0])
```

Comment: above code works, but with my input file it got an error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you used? Are you extracting the lists from a file or where do you get them from?

Comment: yes, i am extracting from a csv file with a data of 1000x1 but i want to convert it into 1x1000 then write into a file

Comment: `modules = print(row[2:])` I think this line is your mistake. Why use print there? Try it without it.

Comment: modules is a list of array that store my data, i have listed as above, my modules input data is same as your inputlist

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original question, if you stored them in array lst then the below would do what you want

```
NewArray =[lst[i][0] for i in range(0,len(lst)) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert your 1-element lists into a single list you can do this:

```
mylists = [
    ['orange'],
    ['apple'],
    ['grape'],
    ['banana'],
    ['mango']
]

l = []
for item in mylists:
    l.append(item[0])

print(l)
```

Output:

```
['orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'banana', 'mango']
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: for which line do you get this error? BTW, have you made sure that your `mylists` is not `None`?

Comment: I get an error in for item in mylists:, i replace mylists with modules

Comment: How are you getting the values of `modules`? From a function? If so make sure that the function is not returning `None`

Comment: modules is a list of array that store my data, i have listed as a bove

Comment: You need to edit your question, and add the code relevant to your problem. Also show the exact structure of the input data (in your case `modules`).

Comment: my modules data is like your mylists which is same as my question

Comment: No, they are not same, there is a slight difference. Hence I am guessing there are more important things to consider. So please edit your question and add necessary details. BTW, try and run the code I have given. It should run without problem. So problem must be in some other part of your code.

Comment: my modules is same as my question above which is a non type not a sequence. I have to Convert NoneType value to sequence string then only can perform with your code

Answer (score 0):

@Tino is asking a valid question. To make it robust, you need to provide from that source the list is coming from. but for now, you can simple append each item individually into a list like;

```
one = []
one.append(a.__getitem__(0) )
one.append(b.__getitem__(0) )
one.append(c.__getitem__(0) )
one.append(d.__getitem__(0) )
one.append(e.__getitem__(0) ) 
print one
```

if you have the item elements list in a sub list, then you can use for loop;

```
my_list = [['orange'],['apple'],['grape'],['banana'],['mango']]
for n in my_list:
    one.append(n[0])
```